# How to apply silicone to an edge (tidily)

Tags: caulking, silicone

How can I coat an edge with silicone?

There are caulking tools for all kinds of joints such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0771HYJVS), but there seems to be no such tools for edges.

I tried using my fingers, but this is far from tidy.

I'd need a caulking tool in such a shape:

[image]

Can such a thing be bought? Where? I tried making it myself by cutting a caulking tool like in the link above, but I cannot get close to the form needed with a knife.

Or can I do it in another way?

What tool or technique do I need  for applying caulk to an edge?

(What do I need that for?
I have a counter top made of chipboard, laminated with melamine resin. There is a little gap between the coating of the top and the coating of the side, so at the edge the chipboard is visible. This is where moisture can get in. By putting silicone on it, I could seal it against moisture.)

Comment: Edges take a lot of abuse, Caulking is not usually used on edges.

Comment: I would coat any porous material with clear nail polish to waterproof it. To do it your way; just hand overcoat it with a lot of extra caulk, which will be messy until you shave along each side on the corner with a new razor blade. You might also consider hotmelt glue as mini-caulk gun shooting waterproof melted plastic instead of latex.

Comment: Yeah, silicone is quite soft and doesn't actually bond that firmly. You might look for a better product or technique.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a little gap between the coating of the top and the coating
> of the side

First is to make sure the "coating" is securely glued down.

I use painter tape to mask off any area that i do not want caulk on, put the tape right up the the edge of the gap on both sides.

Apply the caulk with a caulk gun, careful to not apply too much. I then dip my finger into denatured alcohol or water and smooth the caulk wiping away any excess. Smooth again, pull the tape off, Then **lightly** smooth any anomalies. (*Takes practice to get the right touch*)

A photo of the edge may provide info for more advise or for alternatives to caulk.

Comment: Yeah, when you're filling a void and don't actually need a shaped bead, this is the ticket. Mask, then tool it out. I think I'd use a flat, rigid tool in this case rather than a finger.